# Advantages of using non-bocking io in synchronous http request

Tags: java, nio, apache-httpclient-4.x

When making a synchronous request to a service using http client library, thread is blocked until data is returned. So are there any advantages of using non-blocking io in a synchronous http request?

Use Case: Web application developed using Spring MVC. For certain requests, a synchronous call is made to REST service. Is it advantageous to use an HttpClient library that uses NIO to make calls to the service? [Jetty HttpClient](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+HTTP+Client) uses non-blocking IO. It is not clear to me if [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) from HttpComponents supports NIO.

Comment: Use case: The server side component (say a controller in Spring MVC application) gathers data by making calls to two REST services synchronously.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you implement some sort of service that servers several clients. You will need to achieve a certain degree of parallelism with I/O operations (file access, network communication etc.). Otherwise a single client can block the others ones. You now have two options:

1. You can spawn several threads and each thread uses blocking I/O operations.
2. You use a single thread (or very few) and use non-blocking I/O operations.

Implementing a solution with non-blocking I/O is usually much harder because you have to manage the context of each client yourself. When you use a dedicated thread for each client, the context is naturally given (thread context = client context).

Non-blocking I/O is worth the extra implementation effort if you have a large number of slow clients because you can handle them with a small number of threads. If you used a thread for each client, they'd mainly be sitting there and waiting and would still use huge amounts of memory.

If you aren't implementing a service but a simple application, then non-blocking I/O is certainly not worth it.

**Update**: If I understand the use case correctly, you have a web application which not only serves web pages to web clients but also needs to execute REST requests to serve the web clients. So if you have a very large number of concurrent clients (several thousand or more) and the REST requests take a long time (several seconds), then non-blocking I/O could make sense. But your web server will need to support *asynchronous operations* so you can give the thread back to the server until the REST request has completed. Asynchronous operations were introduced with the Servlert 3.0 specification. So you'll need an up-to-date web server like Tomcat 7.

Comment: @Codo- thanks for the info. I am implementing a client to a REST service. I added use case details above.

Comment: My use case is slightly different. Say request for page http://www.web.com/xyz  is mapped to controller XyzController. XyzController gathers data to serve from database and by calling a REST service.

Comment: @sdny: I think I correctly understood the use case. It's probably my description that could be better. So my answer should fit your use case.

Comment: @codo- thanks for the clarification! Do you mean the server hosting XyzController must support servlet 3.0 spec. I suppose then XyzController must be implemented with some async feature in it. The REST service is a third-party service. I'm mostly interested in call from XyzController to REST service.

Comment: @sdny: Support for asynchronous requests seems to be underway in Spring MVC (see [Spring MVC 3.2 Preview: Introducing Servlet 3, Async Support](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support/)). But it's not quite there yet.